# Bootstrap 4 - Left aligning a large checkbox

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Bootstrap 4.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Enabled" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Enabled" class="form-control" type="checkbox" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Enabled" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

I have a form (see image).  I would like the check box to be underneath the word "Enabled" not centred like the other full width controls.
[image]

If I set "width: auto;" on the checkbox, this does the job, but then displays a small checkbox (I want a large one).  See image.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Enabled" class="control-label"></label>
    <input asp-for="Enabled" class="form-control" style="width: auto;" type="checkbox" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Enabled" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

[image]

My question is, how can I get a large left aligned checkbox on my form?

Comment: Take a look here: [how center a checkbox underneath label using bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49778045/how-center-a-checkbox-underneath-label-using-bootstrap)

Comment: That has now centred both the "Enabled" and the checkbox (Which may be ok).  Cannot get them both left justified though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not tidy by setting an height and width for the checkbox should do the trick.

```css
.checkbox-large {
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Enabled" class="control-label">Enabled</label>
    <input asp-for="Enabled" class="form-control checkbox-large" type="checkbox" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Enabled" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do not mess with already used bootstrap classes by setting manual widths and height you should add class of col-sm to the existing

Comment: @HimanshuAhuja I dont think there is a hard rule against modifying bootstrap4 classes. Why do we have scss and lately css variable if not for customization? And if we make the change locally in the HTML page instead of global css file there is minimal impact. Like I mentioned in the beginning of the answer the solution is not tidy but it gets the job done ! I am not sure the downvote was warranted :(

Answer (score 7):

I am also searched before for the same issue, but not satisfied with the above answer that's why I have done my research and I found a good solution. Just add class "col-sm-1"
in the input tag, you are done.

```
<div class="col-8">
   <input asp-for="IsUrgent" type="checkbox" class="form-control col-sm-1" />
   <span asp-validation-for="IsUrgent" class="text-danger" />
</div>
```

Comment: This is by far the cleanest Answer for this Question. Thanks @Ankit!

Answer (score 1):

you can also use like this if you are not satisfying with class name

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{
  width: 30px; /*Desired width*/
  height: 30px; /*Desired height*/
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none; /* if you want check inside box then remove this line*/
  appearance: none; /* if you want check inside box then remove this line*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Enabled" class="control-label">Enabled</label>
    <input asp-for="Enabled" class="form-control checkbox-large" type="checkbox" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Enabled" class="text-danger"></span>
  </div>
</form>
```